# How to solve linker error in multi-file cpp project

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, c++17, linker-errors

I have 3 files. A header (.h), a cpp (.cpp) & a main (main.cpp).

Inside main I want to include only .h file but not the .cpp to use those functionalities defined.

Here are the files

**person.h**

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>

class Person {
public:
    Person(std::string &&n) : _name(&n), _address(nullptr) {}
    ~Person() {
        delete _name;
        delete _address;
    }

    void set_name(std::string *name); 
    void set_address(std::string *address);

    std::string get_name();
    std::string get_address();
private:
    std::string *_name;
    std::string *_address;    
};

#endif
```

**person.cpp**

```
#include "person.h"

void Person::set_name(std::string *name) {
    _name = name;
} 
void Person::set_address(std::string *address) {
    _address = address;
}

std::string Person::get_name() {
    return *_name;
}
std::string Person::get_address() {
    return *_address;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "person.h"

int main() {
    Person *John = new Person("John Doe");

    std::cout << john->get_name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

All these files reside inside the same directory. I have a CMakeLists.txt defined as well.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.7.1")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project("undirected_graph") 

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp )
```

This is the error I am receiving while compiling

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Person::get_name()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Isn't it the linker's job to link the **person.h** and **person.cpp** and combine them together to **main.cpp** when it's asked to include **person.h** inside **main.cpp**?

BTW everything works if I include **person.cpp** instead of **person.h** inside **main.cpp**.

Comment: You are not compiling or linking `person.cpp`. It's not mentioned anywhere in your make file - how do you expect the compiler or linker to know it even exists?

Comment: As a question-answer scenario I admire the 1st sentence of yours coz that's helpful. The 2nd one is discouraging just so you know. I respect everyone and expect it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Igor Tandetrik, you're not including `person.cpp` in the actual build

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp src/person.cpp)
```

Should get you there.